# Image not displaying on timeline, works in linter

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I have set up a page that specifies an image, using an `og:image` tag with a like link.

If I enter the page URL in the linter, the image displays correctly on both my test and live sites.

However, on the test site, if I like the page, the image is displayed in my timeline. On the live site, however, no image is displayed in my timeline.

There are no other differences between test and live, apart from the first part of the URL.  Is there anything I should look at to help understand why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that it is finding the description text.

Comment: Can you post example of the test page and live page, or screenshot the output of the Lint tool?